# Mysql: How to make index on a table

Tags: mysql, indexing, myisam

I would like to know when i have to put multiple index should i make them under the same "index" or on a different index?

```
INDEX `field1` (`field1`)
INDEX `field2` (`field2`)
```

or

```
INDEX `field1` (`field1`,`field2`)
```

Are there any differneces?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference. An index made out of two columns (or more) is built according to the order of columns you specified. It can be used only when you are searching for the first X fields. Let's say you have an index

```
exampleIndex (`a`, `b`, `c`)
```

It will be used when running queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE a = 1;
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE a = 1 AND b = 2;
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE a = 1 AND b = 2 AND c = 3;
```

It will NOT be used when running queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE b = 2;
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE c = 3;
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE b = 2 AND c = 3;
```

On queries of the first type, having the 3 field index will be quicker than having separate indexes, so deciding how to build the indexes depends on which types of queries you are going to need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a difference. Look: when you gonna run query like

```
SELECT * WHERE a = '1' and b = '2'
```

you will create one index for columns a and b:

```
INDEX `field1` (`field1`,`field2`)
```

Two indexes will be slower.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Ok But IF I need to do only (`SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE a = 1`) the index will not be used at all?

Comment: @yes123 it would be used, but only because you specified `a` first in the index. `SELECT * From tbl where b=2` would not use that index